# how does index signature in typescript works?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an error duplicate number index signature when trying to set object index signature. Here is the working example [click here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ccskyu?file=app/hello.component.ts)

```
    export class HelloComponent implements OnInit  {
      //works
      watched: { [id: number]: boolean } = {} ; //works
      //doesnt work
      watchedOne: { [id: number]: boolean, 
        [fid: number]: boolean } = {} ; // Doesn't Work
      constructor() {}

      watch(talk): void {
        console.log('watch', talk.id);
        this.watched[talk.id] = true;
        this.watchedOne[talk.id] = true; // error
        console.log('watch-obj', this.watched); 
    }
     ngOnInit() {
        this.watch({
          id: 9,
          fid: 4
        });
     }
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in `watchedOne` that you think you need two index signatures?  In your example you are not doing anything with the `fid` property of the object passed into `this.watch()`.  Can you explain what you expect this code to do?

Comment: Does [this code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vkxnlr?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts) act the way you want?  If so, I will build an answer around it.

Comment: I need to know how to work with index signatures do you may create two or  three examples to show me how does it work

Comment: If you want to learn about index signatures without a use case for them you should read the relevant sections of the [TypeScript Handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) or [TypeScript Deep Dive](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html).

Comment: can you workaround with the code in stackblitz?

Comment: Does [this code I've linked here (you can click it)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vkxnlr?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts) work for you or not?  If not, it's because I'm just guessing what the code is supposed to do.  You haven't told us.  I'm not sure if there's a language barrier, sorry.

Comment: I want to know what are the use cases? why do we need index signature? I thought with few examples i can understand what does this do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please read through the sections on index signatures in [The TypeScript Handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) and/or [TypeScript Deep Dive](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html).

Maybe it's not explicit in there *why* you want an index signature.  If you want to define a type and you know the set of properties you care about, including the key names, then you don't want an index signature.  When someone accesses an object without an index signature and uses an unknown key, or assigns a fresh object literal with an unknown key, it's a compiler error:

```
const foo: {bar: boolean, baz: boolean} = {
  bar: true, 
  baz: false, 
  qux: false // error, extra property not expected
};
foo.bar;
foo.baz;
foo.qux; // error, no idea what qux is supposed to be
foo.quux; // error, no idea what quux is supposed to be
```

In the above code, `bar` and `baz` are accepted, but there's an error on `qux`.

If, instead, you want to allow *any* key, without knowing in advance what it will be, then you can add an index signature:

```
const foo: {bar: boolean, baz: boolean, [k: string]: boolean | undefined} = {
  bar: true, 
  baz: false, 
  qux: false // no error
};
foo.bar;
foo.baz;
foo.qux; // boolean | undefined
foo.quux; // boolean | undefined
```

With a single index signature you can set as many properties with the right type of key and value as you want.  The name you give the index key in the signature doesn't matter at all; it is a placeholder for any key of the right type.  The two acceptable types for the key are `string` and `number`.

For example, using a single `number` index:

```
const foo: { [k: number]: boolean | undefined } = { };
foo[0] = true;
foo[1] = false;
foo[2] = void 0; // undefined
foo[12345] = true;
foo[54321] = false;
foo[1.5] = true;
foo[-4] = false;
```

Note that the `k` in the index signature doesn't matter.  I usually use `k`, but you can use `key` or `random` or anything, because it doesn't matter.  It's just a placeholder.

---

That means I can make your above code work by doing something like this:

```
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit  {
  name: string = "karty";
  watched: { [id: number]: boolean } = {} ;
  // single index signature
  watchedOne: { [id: number]: boolean } = {} ;
  constructor() {}

  // type annotation on talk to ensure the right types
  watch(talk: {id: number, fid: number}): void {
    console.log('watch', talk.id);
    this.watched[talk.id] = true;
    this.watchedOne[talk.fid] = true;
    console.log('watch-obj', this.watched); 
}
 ngOnInit() {
    this.watch({
      id: 9,
      fid: 4
    });
 }
}
```

---

Hope that helps; good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need two object signatures, for adding objects with same signatures. But if you need to add objects with different signatures then you may need to add different signatures in your declaration.

Below is an example snippet with different signature declaration. This example snippet can have a number and a string in **watchedOne** variable (because string subsumes number, please refer @Jcalz comments below)

```
 export class HelloComponent implements OnInit  {
  //works
  watched: { [id: number]: boolean } = {} ; //works
   //works now
  watchedOne: {[fid: string]: boolean } = {} ; // Here variable name( like fid) doesn't really matter
  constructor() {}

  watch(talk): void {
    console.log('watch', talk.id);
    this.watched[talk.id] = true;
    this.watchedOne[talk.id] = true; // no error here now
    this.watchedOne[talk.fid] = true; //no error , 
    this.watchedOne[talk.str] = true; //no error
    console.log('watch-obj', this.watched); 
    console.log('watch-one-obj', this.watchedOne);  // this works fine
}
 ngOnInit() {
    this.watch({
      id: 9,
      fid: 4,
      str:"hello"
    });
 }
}
```

Comment: When you say "different type of objects", what do you mean?  It's not obvious from this answer that the only way to do two index signatures is if one is for `string` keys and the other is for `number` keys, and if you *do* specify both, the property value for `number` keys needs to be a *subtype* of the property value for `string` keys.  Both being `boolean` is fine (but unnecessary).

Comment: Why not have two number types in the watchedOne?

Comment: @Jcalz - I have edited my answer accordingly. I was referring to a specific case here

Comment: But a `string` key subsumes `number` keys.  You can always set numeric keys for a `string`-indexed object in TypeScript; you don't need a separate `number` index:   `const foo: { [k: string]: boolean } = {  "str": true,  2: true }; foo[1]=true;`